# Does .cancelAllLocalNotifications clear push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm sending notifications from my parse server, and I want to clear them when the user opens the app. I know local notifications can be cleared with:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

but **that doesn't seem to work with push notifications**. However,

```
PFInstallation.currentInstallation().badge = 0;
```

works to clear badge notifications.

I'm sending notifications from Parse like so:

```
    Parse.Push.send({
      where: pushQuery,
      data: {
        alert:  request.params.message,
        sound: "default",
        badge: 1
      }
    },{
      success: function(){
        console.log(" about to notify friend");
        response.success("yes");
      },
      error: function (error) {
        response.error("nope");
      }
    });
```

Any idea how to clear notifications sent from Parse (non local notifications)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by clearing the notifications?

Comment: @pbush25 The notifications stay in notification center....I want to clear them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`cancelAllLocalNotifications`
```

-will only clear all the Local Notifications as iLikePancakes told.

If you want to cancel all the notifications from the notification center, you first need to increase the badge number to 1 or higher and then set it back to 0. Using it in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunching` makes sure that it is called every time

Answer (score 0):

`.CancelAllLocalNotifications` does not remove notifications from the notification center.

It´s used to cancel the scheduled local notifications, as according to the developer library:

> Cancels the delivery of all scheduled local notifications.

I think setting the badgeNumber to 0 is sufficient to clear the notifications from notification center. Just make sure to do it everytime the app opens.

Answer (score 0):

`.cancelAllLocalNotifications()` is used to cancel scheduled local notification only.

> Cancels the delivery of all scheduled local notifications.

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications)

For push notification, You need to set `badge` to 0 when application launch.